# PHP: Search and replace UNION with it's variations and then replace back

Tags: php

This is a question about string manipulation, not about database security. I am fully aware of PDO and prepared statements.

I want to prevent the word "UNION" from being inserted into my database. It's not the only one, there's a list: "EXECUTE", "DROP", etc. I'm using "UNION" as an example.

My plan is to use str_replace() on any given string (which includes full SQL statements, not just the values) and convert any occurrence of "UNION" into some other arbitary string and then insert the result into the database. E.g. "my union called a vote" would become "my #noinu# called a vote".

When the content is pulled from the database to be displayed on the front-end, any occurrences of "#noinu#" would be replaced with "union".

The words to be replaced are SQL keywords which work regardless of case so I have no case-matching on this.

The problem is that when someone enters, for example, "Union of unions" (capital U on the first word) the result that is eventually printed back out is "union of unions" with small letters.

If I try to account for uppercase, lowercase and proper case then I still miss instances like this, "uNiOn" which would still run in MySQL.

I figured some kind of regular expression would be part of the solution and then I draw a blank.

How can I identify case variations of a word (without manually defining all combinations), replace each variation with it's own custom replacement and then replace them back afterwards?

Comment: You'd have to store something indicating the uniqueness of each string string so the string could be restored. There is no regex which would know the original state of the stored information.

Comment: The replacement string stored have to be always the same ? If no, you could store {union} or {uNiOn}

Comment: Christophe - that sounds like a workable idea. I'm going to give it a try. Thanks!